# What other classes of commutative rings can be defined by requiring that $\{0\}$ is the only proper ideal satisfying some condition?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, big-list

A field is just a commutative ring $R$ such that $\{0_R\}$ is the only proper ideal. Interestingly, there's a similar characterization of integral domains. Given a subset $A$ of $R$, let $A^\perp$ denote the annihilator of $A$, i.e. the set of all $x \in A$ such that $xA \subseteq \{0_R\}$. Then $A^\perp$ is always an ideal. Call a subset $I$ of $R$ an *annihilator* iff $I=A^\perp$ for some $A \subseteq R$; equivalently, iff $I^{\perp\perp} = I$. Then an integral domain is just a commutative ring $R$ such that $\{0_R\}$ is the only proper annihilator.

> **Question.** What other interesting classes of commutative rings can be defined by requiring $\{0\}$ is the only proper ideal satisfying some condition?

Comment: How did you come up with the name *orthic*?

Comment: @k.stm, variant on "orthogonal". Really it should be a variant on "closed" I suppose, since the subsets of a Banach space satisfying $A^{\perp\perp}$ are precisely the closed subspaces IIRC.

Comment: In ring theory such ideals are called [annihilators.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_%28ring_theory%29)

Comment: @BillDubuque, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @goblin Interesting. It's a bit hard to find conditions that apply to both the zero ideal and the whole ring that other ideals in between don't satisfy. (e.g. prime ideals).

Comment: Also "essential ideal" and "superflouous ideal" get disqualified because of this...

Comment: @rschwieb, thanks for the input. I've edited to allow such examples.

Answer (score 1):

A ring $R$ with exactly two non-maximal ideals, $\{0\}$ and $R$, is either a local ring that's not a field or a product of two fields.

Answer (score 1):

A commutative ring is connected (no nontrivial idempotents) iff $\{0\}$ and $R$ are the only finitely generated idempotent ideals.

Near misses:

A commutative ring is semisimple iff $R$ is the only essential ideal.

A commutative ring has trivial Jacobson radical if $\{0\}$ is the only superfluous ideal.

A commutative ring is reduced iff $\{0\}$ is the only nilpotent ideal.